# RUby on rails if else syntax confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

having trouble with the if else -- I am thinking it is a syntax issue but I can not seem to get it. I used the suggestions below and it is still throwing a 500 error. I do not know the exact error because there is a custom error message and "a 500" is the only technical information given. is there a debug mode that I can enable on the dev side that would provide additional information?

What I am trying to do is display a drop down and allow for a selection if you are a "DSD" otherwise the drop down should be disabled, which is why I need the IF statement.

Here is the current if statement that I am running:

**Updated**

```
        <% 
           if (sign_on.acctypw1.strip =="DS") 
               select_tag(:distributor_number_X,  options_for_select(distributors_array), {:style => "width:400px", :disabled => "true"}) 
           else (sign_on.acctypw1.strip =="DSD")               
               select_tag(:distributor_number_X, options_for_select(distributors_array), {:style => "width:400px" })
           end
        %>
```

here is the error from the server log:

```
[Mon Mar 25 09:33:41 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[ pid=8710 thr=77929640 file=utils.rb:176 time=2013-03-25 09:33:42.922 ]: *** Exception SignalException in PhusionPassenger::ClassicRails::ApplicationSpawner (SIGTERM) (process 8710, thread #<Thread:0x94a3950>):
from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.1/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:343:in `select'
from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.1/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:343:in `server_main_loop'
from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.1/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.1/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.1/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:149:in `start'
from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.1/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:219:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rails_application'
from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.1/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.1/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:214:in `block in spawn_rails_application'
from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.1/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.1/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.1/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:213:in `spawn_rails_application'
from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.1/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:132:in `spawn_application'
from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.1/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.1/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.1/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.1/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `<main>'
[Mon Mar 25 09:35:50 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/3.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
 [Mon Mar 25 10:03:31 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
 [Mon Mar 25 10:03:47 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/3.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: you left out an o in your first `options_for_select`

Comment: What's the 500 error?

Comment: @bobkendall When you can post the error, it will help. :)

Answer (score 4):

I assume this is in your view (erb.html file) Your if and else statements also have to go inside `<% %>`.

```
<% if sign_on.acctypw1.strip =="DS" %>
  <%= select_tag(:distributor_number_X, options_for_select(distributors_array), {:style => "width:400px", :disabled => "true"}) %>
<% else sign_on.acctypw1.strip =="DSD" %>             
  <%= select_tag(:distributor_number_X, options_for_select(distributors_array), {:style => "width:400px" })  %>
<% end %>
```

Also, something to keep in mind --

```
<% "This will be evaluated" %>
<%= "This will be evaluated and outputted to your view" %>
```

Comment: from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.1/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:343:in `select'
 from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.1/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:343:in `server_main_loop'

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `elsif` instead of else there.

You also need to wrap your `if/elsif/end` in `<% %>` tags as this is ERB

Comment: made the changes and now getting a 500

Comment: I changed the block of code to the following and I am still getting the logged error above                                                                 <% if (sign_on.acctypw1.strip =="DS") %>
          <%=select_tag(:distributor_number_X,  options_for_select(distributors_array), {:style => "width:400px", :disabled => "true"}) %>
      <% elsif (sign_on.acctypw1.strip =="REP") %>               
           <%=select_tag(:distributor_number_X, options_for_select(distributors_array), {:style => "width:400px", :disabled => "false"}) %>     
       <% end %>

Answer (score -1):

```
<%= 
   if (sign_on.acctypw1.strip =="DS") 
       select_tag(:distributor_number_X,  options_for_select(distributors_array), {:style => "width:400px", :disabled => "true"}) 
   else (sign_on.acctypw1.strip =="DSD")               
       select_tag(:distributor_number_X, options_for_select(distributors_array), {:style => "width:400px" })
   end
%>
```

Comment: this seems the most efficient but still fails a s a 500

Comment: no they have a custom error page catching the error and only displaying that it is a 500 is there and extended bug mode I can enable?

Comment: Can you ssh into the server and look at the log file? Not much we can do to help without the actual error message.

Comment: Why the down vote with no reason? This is a perfectly valid solution as far as i know.